# Graphing problems

Tags: python, graph, plot, matplotlib

My code currently looks like this:

```
a = 3
b = 4
c = 0
d = 1
e = 7
f = 6
g = 5

y = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
x = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
bar(y, x, linewidth = 3)
show()
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Oh, bar() is a graphing tool? I thought it came standard with Python.

Comment: Your code works fine for me using python 2.7 and `matplotlib` version 1.1.0.

Comment: No. I thought `bar` was some function of you (like `foo`...) Did you you mean `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` (or something like that?) In that case, try it with a list istead of a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball hints that you're trying to use `matplotlib`. In that case, change your `x` and `y` from `tuples` into `lists`:

```
y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
x = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
```

Comment: I tried but im getting this error now: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: please post the exact line of code which gives you the latter error. Better, make it a separate post. Better yet, read up on the python's basics.